# JS как в тетрисе реализовать падение фигуры при нажатии клавиши

Tags: javascript

Написал тетрис на JS. Реализовал что только можно. Но я захотел добавить функцию, которая по нажатию клавиши пробел, роняла фигуру на дно стакана. И тут все оказалось не так классно как хотелось бы. Функция роняет фигуру на дно стакана,

```js
let main = document.querySelector(".main");
const scroeElem = document.getElementById("score");
const levelElem = document.getElementById("level");
const nextTetroElem = document.getElementById("next-tetro");
const nextedTetroElem = document.getElementById("nexted-tetro");
const startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pause");
const gameOver = document.getElementById("game-over");
let playfield = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

let score = 0;
let gameTimerID;
let currentLevel = 1;
let isPaused = true;
let possibleLevels = {
  1: {
    scorePerLine: 10,
    speed: 400,
    nextLevelScore: 50,
  },
  2: {
    scorePerLine: 15,
    speed: 300,
    nextLevelScore: 100,
  },
  3: {
    scorePerLine: 20,
    speed: 200,
    nextLevelScore: 1000,
  },
  4: {
    scorePerLine: 30,
    speed: 100,
    nextLevelScore: 2000,
  },
  5: {
    scorePerLine: 50,
    speed: 50,
    nextLevelScore: Infinity,
  },
};

let figures = {
  O: [
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1],
  ],
  I: [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
  ],
  S: [
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  Z: [
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  L: [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  J: [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  T: [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  D: [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
  ],
  R: [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
  ],
  P: [
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
  ],
  K: [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
};

let activeTetro = getNewTetro();
let nextTetro = getNewTetro();
let nextedTetro = getNewTetro();

function draw() {
  let mainInnerHTML = "";
  for (let y = 0; y < playfield.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < playfield[y].length; x++) {
      if (playfield[y][x] === 1) {
        mainInnerHTML += '<div class="cell movingCell"></div>';
      } else if (playfield[y][x] === 2) {
        mainInnerHTML += '<div class="cell fixedCell"></div>';
      } else {
        mainInnerHTML += '<div class="cell"></div>';
      }
    }
  }
  main.innerHTML = mainInnerHTML;
}

function drawNextTetro() {
  let nextTetroInnerHTML = "";
  for (let y = 0; y < nextTetro.shape.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < nextTetro.shape[y].length; x++) {
      if (nextTetro.shape[y][x]) {
        nextTetroInnerHTML += '<div class="cell movingCell"></div>';
      } else {
        nextTetroInnerHTML += '<div class="cell"></div>';
      }
    }
    nextTetroInnerHTML += "<br/>";
  }
  nextTetroElem.innerHTML = nextTetroInnerHTML;
}

function drawNextedTetro() {
  let nextedTetroInnerHTML = "";
  for (let y = 0; y < nextedTetro.shape.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < nextedTetro.shape[y].length; x++) {
      if (nextedTetro.shape[y][x]) {
        nextedTetroInnerHTML += '<div class="cell movingCell"></div>';
      } else {
        nextedTetroInnerHTML += '<div class="cell"></div>';
      }
    }
    nextedTetroInnerHTML += "<br/>";
  }
  nextedTetroElem.innerHTML = nextedTetroInnerHTML;

}

function removePrevActiveTetro() {
  for (let y = 0; y < playfield.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < playfield[y].length; x++) {
      if (playfield[y][x] === 1) {
        playfield[y][x] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

function addActiveTetro() {
  removePrevActiveTetro();
  for (let y = 0; y < activeTetro.shape.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < activeTetro.shape[y].length; x++) {
      if (activeTetro.shape[y][x] === 1) {
        playfield[activeTetro.y + y][activeTetro.x + x] =
          activeTetro.shape[y][x];
      }
    }
  }
}

function rotateTetro() {
  const prevTetroState = activeTetro.shape;

  activeTetro.shape = activeTetro.shape[0].map((val, index) =>
    activeTetro.shape.map((row) => row[index]).reverse()
  );

  if (hasCollisions()) {
    activeTetro.shape = prevTetroState;
  }
}

function hasCollisions() {
  for (let y = 0; y < activeTetro.shape.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < activeTetro.shape[y].length; x++) {
      if (
        activeTetro.shape[y][x] &&
        (playfield[activeTetro.y + y] === undefined ||
          playfield[activeTetro.y + y][activeTetro.x + x] === undefined ||
          playfield[activeTetro.y + y][activeTetro.x + x] === 2)
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function removeFullLines() {
  let canRemoveLine = true,
    filledLines = 0;
  for (let y = 0; y < playfield.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < playfield[y].length; x++) {
      if (playfield[y][x] !== 2) {
        canRemoveLine = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (canRemoveLine) {
      playfield.splice(y, 1);
      playfield.splice(0, 0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
      filledLines += 1;
    }
    canRemoveLine = true;
  }

  switch (filledLines) {
    case 1:
      score += possibleLevels[currentLevel].scorePerLine;
      break;
    case 2:
      score += possibleLevels[currentLevel].scorePerLine * 3;
      break;
    case 3:
      score += possibleLevels[currentLevel].scorePerLine * 6;
      break;
    case 4:
      score += possibleLevels[currentLevel].scorePerLine * 12;
      break;
  }

  scroeElem.innerHTML = score;

  if (score >= possibleLevels[currentLevel].nextLevelScore) {
    currentLevel++;
    levelElem.innerHTML = currentLevel;
  }
}

function getNewTetro() {
  const possibleFigures = "IOLJTSZDRPK";
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  const newTetro = figures[possibleFigures[rand]];

  return {
    x: Math.floor((10 - newTetro[0].length) / 2),
    y: 0,
    shape: newTetro,
  };
}

function fixTetro() {
  for (let y = 0; y < playfield.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < playfield[y].length; x++) {
      if (playfield[y][x] === 1) {
        playfield[y][x] = 2;
      }
    }
  }
}

function moveTetroDown() {
  activeTetro.y += 1;
  if (hasCollisions()) {
    activeTetro.y -= 1;
    fixTetro();
    removeFullLines();
    activeTetro = nextTetro;
    if (hasCollisions()) {
      reset();
    }
    nextTetro = nextedTetro;
    nextedTetro = getNewTetro()
  }
}

function dropTetro() {
  for (let y = activeTetro.y; y < playfield.length; y++) {
    activeTetro.y += 1;
    if (hasCollisions()) {
      activeTetro.y -= 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  isPaused = true;
  clearTimeout(gameTimerID);
  playfield = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ];
  draw();
  gameOver.style.display = "block";
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!isPaused) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      activeTetro.x -= 1;
      if (hasCollisions()) {
        activeTetro.x += 1;
      }
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      activeTetro.x += 1;
      if (hasCollisions()) {
        activeTetro.x -= 1;
      }
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      moveTetroDown();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      rotateTetro();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      dropTetro();
    }

    updateGameState();
  }
};

function updateGameState() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    addActiveTetro();
    draw();
    drawNextTetro();
    drawNextedTetro();
  }
}

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.innerHTML === "Pause") {
    e.target.innerHTML = "Keep Playing...";
    clearTimeout(gameTimerID);
  } else {
    e.target.innerHTML = "Pause";
    gameTimerID = setTimeout(startGame, possibleLevels[currentLevel].speed);
  }
  isPaused = !isPaused;
});

startBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.target.innerHTML = "Start again";
  isPaused = false;
  gameTimerID = setTimeout(startGame, possibleLevels[currentLevel].speed);
  gameOver.style.display = "none";
});

scroeElem.innerHTML = score;
levelElem.innerHTML = currentLevel;

draw();

function startGame() {
  moveTetroDown();
  if (!isPaused) {
    updateGameState();
    gameTimerID = setTimeout(startGame, possibleLevels[currentLevel].speed);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#game {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* .wave{
          display: none;
      } */

.main {
  width: 320px;
  height: 620px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border: 10px solid white;
  font-size: 0;
  background: url(../image/costel.png);
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movingCell {
  background-color: blue;
}

.fixedCell {
  background-color: red;
}

#next-tetro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#nexted-tetro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#game-over {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Tetris</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game">
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
    <div>Level: <span id="level">0</span></div>
    <div>Score: <span id="score">0</span></div>
    <div class="main">
      <!-- <ul id="body_slides">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                </ul> -->
    </div>
    <div id="game-over">Game <br>over</br>
    </div>
    <div id="next-tetro"></div>
    <div id="nexted-tetro"></div>
    <audio class="wave" src="audio/korobeyniki.mp3" controls autoplay loop></audio>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Функция роняет фигуру на дно стакана по при нажатии клавиши, а также при нажатии клавиши пробел происходит ускорение падения последующих фигур.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведите функцию:

```
function nextTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(gameTimerID);
  gameTimerID = setTimeout(startGame, possibleLevels[currentLevel].speed);
}
```

и всегда вызывайте ее вместо строчки

```
gameTimerID = setTimeout(startGame, possibleLevels[currentLevel].speed);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @Vladislove Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.